# Unable to initialise Binding var in initialiser

Tags: swiftui

In my below code , no matter what I do I always get error for the expression that I use for imageData in init,  I use it as a wrapper for Binding , I have tried `_imageData = Binding(projectedValue: $imageData)` but I keep getting error, how can I satisfy the Binding in initialiser, kindly guide, thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddView: View {
    @Binding var imageData: UIImage?   <----------Use
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var friendName: String = ""
  
    let savePath = FileManager.documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SavedFriends")
    
    var save: (Friend) -> Void
    
    init(save: @escaping  (Friend) -> Void) {
       
        self.save = save
        _friendName = State(initialValue: "")
         _imageData = Binding(projectedValue: $imageData)  <----error
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("your friends name", text: $friendName)
                Image(uiImage: imageData!) <--------used here
                    .resizable()
                  //  .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .scaledToFit()
                }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        let newFriend = Friend(picName: friendName, id: UUID())
                            save(newFriend)
                            dismiss()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }

                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            }
        }
   
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Variable 'self.imageData' used before being initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide initialiser you have to initialise everything in it, ie. including binding.

Here is fixed variant

```
init(imageData: Binding<UIImage?>, save: @escaping  (Frient) -> Void) {

    self.save = save
    _friendName = State(initialValue: "")
    _imageData = imageData
}
```

Comment: If you don't provide then your next code `Image(uiImage: imageData!)` will crash, so provided answer considered this case. Anyway you have to initialise all properties if you provided explicit `init` - everything else if up to you how to manage. If you need optional binding itself (not only wrapped value) then look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701305/12299030.